# jQuery Countdown on expiry new layout not new url

Tags: jquery, countdown

Im using jquery countdown http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I want the page to refresh when the countdown is finished and reload a new page layout ( on the same url) I figured out how to redirect but am racking my head to figure out page refresh to new layout.

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the page to refresh when the
>   countdown is finished and reload a new
>   page layout ( on the same url) I
>   figured out how to redirect but am
>   racking my head to figure out page
>   refresh to new layout.

If you want to refresh the page, you can do this:

```
document.location.reload();
```

But off course you would put above line where necessary for example the counter finishes.

Comment: Found this event:  onExpiry in the countdown js but still cant figure it out how to make teh page refresh to a new layout

Answer (score 0):

Personally i prefere the jquery plugin [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/).

Just add to open in a new window :

```
$.doTimeout( 2000, function(){
  return window.open(location.href, '_blank');
});
```

Or just this to open in the same window :

```
$.doTimeout( 2000, function(){
  return window.location(location.href);
});
```

Comment: Hey, I dont want to go to go to new url i want the content on the page to refresh to new content / layout when the timer is up.